# Use Ruby Script in Google App Engine to transfer files from storage to big query

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Can I use Ruby Scripts in Google Cloud Platform App Engine to load data from Cloud Storage to Big Query? And if yes, how can I deploy these scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ruby scripts can be used to interact with BigQuery, and from within an App Engine deployed application.

To start it's as simple as running;
 `gem install google-cloud-bigquery`

The source code can be found on github [google-cloud-ruby](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-bigquery).

The official Google quickstart for Ruby and the Big Query API [Quickstart: BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries).

You will also need to review ruby integration with App Engine's Flex environment [Ruby runtime for App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime)